# Recyclerview automatically scroll up when data inserted

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm suffering with one problem that when I add data to array list and then add it into adapter after that when I set it to recycler view adapter it jumps to top automatically how can I prevent it like I want to add data in virtual space I also tried with use of -

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    innerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
```

but it not working. how can I solve it?

add some code for scrolling up

```
if (isScrollUp) {
                            isEnable = true;
                            userChats.addAll(0, model.data);
                                                       innerChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    nnerChatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                                }
                            }, 1);
                        }
```

Comment: If you are setting all time adapter than this will be happen. share more code for your help!

Comment: where do you call 'setAdapter()' method?

Comment: Ronak Thakkar i'm setting adapter in onCreateview method .

Comment: @Madhav_nimavat see my answer you will get proper solution for it

Comment: Thnxs Ashish and ND1010_ both answer are right thnxs both for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello if you want to scroll down after add data to adapter.Add below method after notifyDataSetChanged() called.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(new_data_size);
            }
        }, 1);
```

Comment: Ok sure and if you want to scroll up than just add position to "0".\

Comment: ashish my net is too slow so i'm not able to get data so i will update you after some time.

Comment: ashish it directly jump me to bottom

Comment: i'm adding at top of array list at 0 position

Comment: What you want ? Jump to bottom or bottom to Top?

Comment: ashish i'm adding data at both top and bottom there is no problem when i add at bottom but problem occurs when i add at top of arrraylist means at 0 position it jumps me to top

Comment: Sorry brother i am not getting your point. Please clarify my question to you
q) In which scenario want to scroll your recycle view.

Comment: at see i'm developing chat type module in which it shows latest records but if user scrolls up then it add older 10 records at top means at 0 position but at that time recyclerview jumps me to top of data  now you get it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146386/discussion-between-ashish-and-madhav-nimavat).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
Don't update the entire RecyclerView. [Ref Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        innerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position /* position of newly added item */);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you can use requestFocus() method on any other top element of your view.

```
  top_element.requestFocus();
```

Comment: aashutosh kumar can you help me how can implement it ?

Comment: yes, have u any top element in the view except recyclerview

Comment: Aashutosh kumar i'm using recyclerview